# Awesome WM: what do the icons of the title bar mean?

Tags: awesome-wm

can someone tell me what is the meaning of the icons in the title bar? A rocket, a plus, a star.. Im very curious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the file names of the icons. The first component describes the meaning: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/tree/master/themes/default/titlebar

- The plus is for sticky windows. These are windows which are visible on all tags (normally windows are only visible if one of their tags is selected).
- The star is for ontop. These windows ignore the normal stacking order and are ontop of everything else.
- The rocket is for maximized windows. These windows ignore the current layout and use all the available space.
- The arrow is for floating windows. These windows also ignore the current layout, but they can be freely resized to any size.
- The cross is a close button. It closes windows! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I switch between thse window flags (keyboard shortcut)?

Comment: Look at the default config and search for the names of these, I guess. There doesn't seem to be a binding for sticky, ontop is mod+t, maximized is mod+m, floating is mod+ctrl+space, kill is mod+shift+c