# Plus symbol in task bar

Tags: awesome-wm

What does the "+" Symbol in the task bar mean? [This is a screenshot with the "+".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mukgN.png)

It happens, that the clients with a "+" do not tile when opening another client. The "+" disappears, when maximizing the client, but then it does not tile either.

Any ideas how to deactivate the "+" status?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awesome WM: what do the icons of the title bar mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475104/awesome-wm-what-do-the-icons-of-the-title-bar-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your firefox is maximized.

> The "+" disappears, when maximizing the client,

You mean when unmaximizing, right?

Here is a link to the line of the code which uses a (bold) plus as indication of maximized clients: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/3cfb577387d52e898455a64344f73409bc6f481b/lib/awful/widget/tasklist.lua#L243

Comment: Thank you, you're totally right, + means "maximized". But if not maximized, the window is floating ('✈') and maximized_horizontal ('⬌') and maximized_vertical ('⬍'). The following issue helped me with this problem tough: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44364/how-to-maximise-a-window-horizontal-or-vertically.

Answer (score 10):

I've just had a related problem where my chromium window would always start maximized, which is the plus sign. I added a rule to prevent this, as suggested in the link at the bottom.

> ```
> { rule = { class = "chromium" },
>   properties = { maximized = false } },
> ```

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1599

Comment: I also had to add `floating = false` to make it perfect.

Comment: I had the same problem with keepass. That solved it!